# \newcommand element gets displayed on new page, when too much input in it

Tags: layout

Im trying to create a new element with \newcommand which looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\commentontext}[2]
{
    \begin{minipage}{.10\textwidth}
        \hspace{-0.5in} \hfill \footnotesize{#1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill \vline \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.80\textwidth}
       #2
    \end{minipage}
    \break
}
```

Everything works fine and I can use this command, I can also use a few of those elements after each other. BUT when I get a lot of text into my second parameter, the element won't stay on the page but gets displayed on a new page, although I would like it to get displayed one element after the other and only go onto the next page when the previous page is filled up.

Is there a command or a package I can use to change it's behavior?

EDIT:
Here is an example of how this looks like. You can see on the first page there is enough white space that could be filled with the beginning of the second element. The second element starts at the second page though.

[image: First page]
[image: Second page]

This is how I am using the commentontext command

```
\commentontext{Testing}
{
   \lipsum[1] 
}

\commentontext{Test}
{
    \lipsum[3-8]
}
```

Comment: please provide a test file that shows the problem, it is hard to debug a fragment. note your command adds a lot of white space, `\ commentontext` adds paragraph indent, a word space a box of width .1\textwirdth  a word space  the width of a line (no word space to teh right of the line) a box of width .8\textwidth another  word space then a forced line break ??? (that presumably generates underful box warnings?) . It isn't clear what bad break you are getting, you can not have  a page break in a minipage, so if the entire box does not fit on the page the whole minipage must go to the next page.

Comment: Please note that `\footnotesize` doesn't take an argument, it is a switch, so it affects everything in the current group that follows it, so instead of `\footnotesize{<foo>}` would be `{\footnotesize #1}`, but in this case this isn't necessary, as the `minipage` acts as a group delimiting it.

Comment: @Skillmon Oh yes thanks, I still have issues with displaying my text to my liking but this is a battle for another day :). Never the less thanks for the info.

Comment: @HelmutK.: Currently you set the "left column" vertically centred with respect to the "right column." Would you be okay if they're vertically aligned at the top of one another instead?

Comment: as requested in the first comment, please provide a test document. The text you show does not fit on the first page, and you have placed it in a minipage so it can not be split over pages (that is the main function of a minipage) so it has to go to the next page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh ok, so minipage makes it impossible, that the second \commentontext will start right after the first one?
Also this is the test document, I do realize that "Test" is not displayed. I have no idea why this is the case.
Do you have an idea how I could create a similar command without minipage?

Comment: You have not said what you want the layout to be nor provided a test file just provided a fragment showing a mimipage so all I can do is comment that the purpose of a mimipage is to prevent page breaks in that region. I can't say what you should do instead

Comment: @HelmutK.: You can get a top-aligned left column if you use [`paracol`](//ctan.org/pkg/paracol).